# Cannot launch system with no battery icon

Tags: macos, mac

I use a 2017 12" MacBook. It suddenly shut out due to lack of battery. Then I recharged it still does not start with the no battery icon.

The battery should be 100% as I plugged it for a day and prior to yesterday it worked without any problems.

How can I start it again? Is this hardware issue? Or does bringing to Apple Store is the only option here?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in the MacBook charger and try to start it.

If it doesn't start, it's recommended to get it inspected at an Apple Store or by an authorized technician.